# Timer Job not running

Tags: 2007

I created a custom timer job and deployed it into my development farm. The job runs fine. The thins is that after I deployed it to the QA farm. The status of the job says succeeded in central admin, but nothing happens. I added extra logging and nothing is being logged.

I thought it was something with that specific timer job, so I created another timer job that just has an assert and displays a pop up when it runs. Again, it just in the dev farm but not in the QA one. In this case though, the status of the job says Initialized and 0% completed, but no pop up.

I think it has something to do with permissions, but I cannot find what it is. Any toughts??

Comment: Have you tried to debug your timer job?

Comment: Yes, I tries, but did not work for me. I installed the remote debugger tools in the server. I ran it, and then connected from my dev machine. The thing is that VS tells me that there is no symbols loaded for the code. I'm doing something wrong here :P

Comment: Perhaps it's a good idea to add some more logging to your app to see where an exception is (possibly) thrown. Also add some informational logging. You can do this in the eventviewer http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307024 or in the Sharepoint logs: http://salviashish.wordpress.com/2009/05/16/writing-in-sharepoint-logs/ That way you'll probably be able to find out where the job is quiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I erased the cache of the server and the job started working again. However each time the I change the schedule of the timer job, I have to clear the cache again.

Comment: how did you clear the cache?

Comment: follow these steps http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josrod/archive/2007/12/12/clear-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache-for-timer-job-and-psconfig-errors.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy to your QA environment have you ensured that you have restarted the timer service on all of your SharePoint boxes? The OWSTimer service will cache DLLs and cause very strange issues when trying to debug and test new timer jobs.

Comment: Yes, I even restarted the server.